# React native Tab background Change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabs, react-tabs

I'm using the simple react native tab. The tab works fine but it shows the default blue color background of the  tag. That means About Courses and Chat are in a row and getting blue color by default. How could I change it?**Also, how could I change '  '**  this heading font-family, text color, and others property?

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
  <Tabs tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
    <Tab heading="About Test" tabStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>
      <View>
        <Text>Hi THis is from ABout</Text>
      </View>
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading="Courses">
      <Text>Hi this is from Courses</Text>
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading="Chat">
      <Text>This is from Chat</Text>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you talking about `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`??

Comment: import { Container, Tab, Tabs, StyleProvider } from 'native-base';
but the whole line is getting blue background.   mainly <Tabs> </Tabs>  background is not changing

Comment: I would suggest you to use [Material Top Bar Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator). Its docs are super easy and to the point.

Comment: so can you please tell me to change the background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like this

```
    <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue' }}>
        <Tab
          heading="About Test"
          tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'orangered' }}
          textStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: '100' }}
          activeTextStyle={{ fontWeight: '800',color: 'white' }}>
          <View>
            <Text>Hi THis is from ABout</Text>
          </View>
        </Tab>

        <Tab
          heading="Courses"
          tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'orangered' }}
          textStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: '100' }}
          activeTextStyle={{ fontWeight: '800',color: 'white'  }}>
          <Text>Hi this is from Courses</Text>
        </Tab>

        <Tab
          heading="Chat"
          tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'orangered' }}
          textStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: '100' }}
          activeTextStyle={{ fontWeight: '800',color: 'white'  }}>
          <Text>This is from Chat</Text>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

For `underline` styling just add

```
tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue' }}
```

to the `<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue' }} />`

Also on Android I got to see that not setting `activeTextStyle` color shows no text..To fix this add

```
activeTextStyle={{ fontWeight: '800', color: 'white' }}> // Color as you desire
```

For removing border around the box

Add `tabContainerStyle={{ elevation: 0 }}` to `<Tabs />`, like this

```
 <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue' }} tabContainerStyle={{ elevation: 0 }} >
```

To change Background Color of inside tabs space add `style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}` to `<Tab />`, like this

```
<Tab
  heading="About Test"
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}> // This line right here
      <View>
        <Text>Hi THis is from ABout</Text>
      </View>
</Tab>
```

Check working example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/native-base-tabs)

Comment: Thanks that works for me but i want an underline on selected tabs. How to do it?
Also selected tab's background is orangered but its text is unvisible. Cant't see it. How to make it visible?

Comment: Check my answer I've added way to style the `underline` also.. Also check the snack link to see the working example

Comment: Hi just awesome. thanks a lot. But my selected tab's text is not visible. How to make it visible? I'm using android divice

Comment: Added fix for where Text was not visible..now it will be visible

Comment: Super.. Just awesome. It works like i wanted. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer..Consider Accepting it..Thanks.It willl help others with the same problem in future

Comment: I'm facing another problem. Can't  fix my tabs border like the given design

i've upload two screenshot in drvie and shared link. There are two picture one is  given and one is that i've made. Please have a look and let me know.


https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DdAEMJ6wrFZloB0byvdpPSeQcEK-EzE1?usp=sharing

Comment: You want to make your border length small and thin. Right??

Comment: There will be no border . Just Text will be visible and same background all over the screen. You can see the desgin image that i'm following. But my code shows an border or something like divider around the Tabs

Comment: Added solution for your problem

Comment: That works fine . Great.
But another problem is the text under  Tab tag's  background Color is not changing. For Example, I'm selecting About Test   it shows below that 'Hi This is from about test.' .  But the back ground color of 'Hi this is from ABout Test Is not changing.'   I want a Grey background color of 'Hi THis is from ABout'

Comment: I've added solution for that also

Comment: You're really great .Can't thank you enough man. Is there any system at StackOverflow to follow you?

Comment: Happy to help!. If your problem is solved please Accept the answer so that it may help others on Stack Overflow...You can contact me throught [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kartikeyvaish/).

Comment: I dont know how to accept answer. please explain

Comment: See the tick button in my answer You have to click it.. Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/Bs2TW3O.png) image to find out. I've marked it with an arrow

Comment: How can i set the box shadow at bottom? See the gievn  design image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232003/discussion-between-kartikey-vaish-and-megh).